# Type X is missing the following properties from type 'postType[]': length, pop, push, concat, and 28 more

Tags: angular, typescript

I am trying to do something very simple here. I have a TweetInterface.ts

```js
// TweetInterface.ts
export interface postType {
  posterId: string,
  username: string,
  postText: string,
  encryptedText?: string,
  iv?: string,
  locks?: Array<string>,
  taggedUsers?: Array<string>
}
```

that is being used in

```js
// home.ts
import TweetList from '../../components/PostBox/TweetList';
import { postType } from '../../components/PostBox/types/TweetInterface';

function Home() {

  const placeholder = {
    tweets: {
      posterId: "abcd",
      username: "@abcd",
      postText: "abcdefgh",
      encryptedText: "abcd",
      iv: "abcd",
      locks: ["a", "b"],
      taggedUsers: ["c", "d"]
    }
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <NewTweetForm newTweetInput={undefined} handleNewTweet={undefined} handleSubmit={undefined} />
      <TweetList tweets={placeholder} />
      //         ^^^^^^ This is where the bug arises from
    </div>
  );
}

export default Home;
```

but I keep getting the following error TS2740,

```
Type '{ tweets: { posterId: string; username: string; postText: string; encryptedText: string; iv: string; locks: string[]; taggedUsers: string[]; }; }' is missing the following properties from type 'postType[]': length, pop, push, concat, and 28 more.  TS2740
```

I have tried everything as a beginner but any help from you guys is plausible. Thanks in advance.

Comment: TweetList is expecting an array of tweets, not a standalone tweet. Try `tweets={[placeholder]}`

Comment: @NicholasTower, yes I tried that prior to posting yet it again gives me the same error with a different code i.e. TS2739. Any suggestions?

Comment: Ah, i see. `placeholder.tweets` contains a single tweet. So if `placeholder` stays as written, you need to pluck out the tweets object and put it into an array. For example: `tweets={[placeholder.tweets]}`.